# How to get all dates that they have at least one Event on that day from a given date range?

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am having a `SQLite` database which contains a table `Events` with `start and end dates`. I would like to get a `Set` (could be an array without duplicates) of dates that they at least have an Event on that day let's say from 1st of August to 20th of August.

Let's take some example events:

```
Event 1 from 02.08.2016 to 07.08.2016
Event 2 from 10.08.2016 to 12.08.2016
Event 3 from 11.08.2016 to 15.08.2016

Then the outcome should be: 
[02.08.2016, 03.08.2016, 04.08.2016, 05.08.2016, 06.08.2016, 07.08.2016, 10.08.2016, 11.08.2016, 12.08.2016, 13.08.2016, 14.08.2016, 15.08.2016]

where 11.08.2016 and 12.08.2016 are not repeating.
```

**NB:** I am expecting an answer that could solve this problem **only using SQL** rather combining some programming code. I need that on a mobile device (iOS) where I am trying to optimize the user experience and performance.

Comment: Create a calendar table, full of every date you could need, then join against it and select distinct dates from it.

Comment: What is the minimum SQLite version you have available?

Comment: @CL. SQLite 3.7.13 under iOS 7.

Comment: Then you cannot use CTEs. It might be easier to generate the list of dates in your code.

Comment: @CL. Yes I think so. But if you can find the solution using CTEs why not, please post the answer.

Comment: Using a CTE to generate the sequential dates isn't generally an efficient use of resources.  A calendar table or a number table takes up just a few kB for Years worth of dates, and makes the query simpler and more streamlined.  If this has to be in SQL, I'd strongly advise using one.  If the few kB memory cost is too much, loop through it in your app and generate the dates there.

Comment: Can anyone post the solution with CTE, at least it could be the right point of time to lean about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of creating a date table with recursive CTE and using it to select dates you need:

```
WITH RECURSIVE
  cnt(dt) AS 
  (
     SELECT MIN(startDate) FROM Events
     UNION ALL
     SELECT date(dt,'+1 day') FROM cnt 
           WHERE dt < (SELECT MAX(endDate) FROM Events)
           LIMIT 10000
  )
SELECT DISTINCT dt 
FROM cnt
JOIN Events ON dt BETWEEN startDate AND endDate
ORDER BY dt;
```

<kbd>[SQL fiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5/0f0ff/6)</kbd>